# PHPMailer not sending mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an order confirmation and also notify the seller about a user purchase. However, PHPMailer only sends the first email. Here's quick and dirty:

```
$bodytext = 'Mail.';
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'mail@mail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Sender';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress($_REQUEST['sahkoposti']);
$email->AddAttachment($path, 'kuitti'.$ordernumber.'.pdf');
return $email->Send();
?>

<?php

//send message to seller


$bodytext = 'Mail.';
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'mail@mail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Sender';
$email->Subject   = 'Tilaus vastaanotettu';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress("mail@mail.com");
$email->AddAttachment($path, 'kuitti'.$ordernumber.'.pdf');
return $email->Send();
?>
```

Is it even possible to send multiple emails from one script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, however you're using `return` in the first statement, which will stop execution of the function. Remove the first return (just use `$email->Send();`) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The second email does not get executed because you are **returning** right after sending the first email, you should change:

```
return $email->Send();
```

for this:

```
$email->Send();
```